# Plot censored events in R version 3.3.2

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to generate a KM curve and would like censored events to be shown in the graph as usual (like a cross or equivalent).

I am using the R version above and have updated packages "survival", "KMsurv", and "rms".

I attempted code shown in some websites with no success.

Example from http://www.visualcinnamon.com/2013/07/plotting-survival-analysis-results-in-r.html

```
library(survival)
data(colon)
fit = survfit(Surv(time,status)~rx, data=colon)
plot(fit, xlab="Time", ylab="Survival Probability", main="Kaplan-Meier plot")
```

I do generate a KM curve, but censored events are not represented graphically.

I also tried (using rms package):

```
fit <- npsurv(Surv(time,status)~rx, data=colon)
survplot(fit)
```

Nothing worked. What am I missing?

PS: mark.time in base R worked, but I am specifically interested a cumulative probability plot (AKA "inverted KM") and I don't think this can be done easily in base R. It is super easy with rms using argument: 'fun = function(x) {1 - x}'

Comment: Sorry, seems like I messed up with how to post code appropriately and it all got joined in one line. My apologies.

Comment: have you tried to set parameter `mark.time` to `TRUE` ? it should help... (see `?plot.survfit` for details...)

Comment: Thanks Cath, both for editing my post and for pointing out how to do this with base R. Is there an equivalent parameter for 'survplot' function in the RMS package?

Comment: At one time I thought  that you had checkmarked the answer. If you explain why it was removed, I or another might be able to address the outstanding problems.

Comment: Hi 42, not sure what you mean. Sorry. I had no intention to remove any answers, they were quite helpful ...

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you one (or more)  of these three calls (documented in the `?points.survfit` page which was in turn linked from the `?plot.survfit` page) :

```
 plot(fit, xlab="Time", ylab="Haz Probability", main="Kaplan-Meier plot",
            fun="cumhaz")  # the cumulative Hazard is 1-Survival
 plot(fit, xlab="Time", ylab="Haz Probability", main="Kaplan-Meier plot",
           fun="cumhaz", conf.int=TRUE)
 plot(fit, xlab="Time", ylab="Haz Probability", main="Kaplan-Meier plot",
            fun="cumhaz", conf.int=TRUE, mark.time=TRUE) # censoring markers
```

The last one produces:

[image]

Comment: Thanks sir. That works very well. I also want to let people know of the package "survminer" and it's function "ggsurvplot" which is pretty amazing. Of course, I found this after posting my question here.                                       http://www.sthda.com/english/rpkgs/survminer/ggsurvplot.html